How many of Trump's trials can finish by election day?
This isn't a crystal ball question - I understand that there could be new "revelations" or legal stalls - either from the standard pace of justice or legal maneuvering. In the fastest-case-scenario, how many trials involving former President and Republican nominee Trump could finish before Election day? An ideal answer would indicate a range for trial completion dates for each of the legal challenges he faces. The legal proceedings in which he is likely an unindicted co-conspirator are beyond the scope of the question.

Would this be more suited for law.SE maybe? They may know more about the typical runtimes of the US legal system. Also, did you search it? The topic is quite popular and may have answers already somewhere. I found for example https://www.pbs.org/newshour/politics/trumps-2024-trials-where-they-stand-and-what-to-expect

VTC - Speculation "predictions for future events".

Probably only one.

Though Trump has been charged in four different criminal cases, this case [the hush money one] is likely the only one to reach a trial ahead of the 2024 general election.

The other cases aren't likely to reach trial, let alone finish, by election day.

For some of these trials they had years of investigation time. One wonders why it took so long to start the trials but that is another question.

The judge on the classified documents case (possibly the strongest / most substantial case) has been accused of slow-walking it

There is a decent chance that the confidential documents case could go to trial before the election. There is an outside chance the the GA election fraud case could go to trial before the election. The DC January 6 related cases is very unlikely to go to trial before the election. One or more pending civil cases could also be resolved before then.
